# Show GStreamer Video in Browser

Tags: web, browser, raspberry-pi, real-time, gstreamer

My PC is connected to the GroundPi via Ethernet, displaying the video on the PC using the following GStreamer command works just fine:
`gst-launch-1.0.exe udpsrc port=5000 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink sync=false`.

Now I would like to display the video in a browser window. What is the best way to achieve this? I cannot, of course change the `udpsource` part, however, I am free to use any kind of sink. It is essential that the video be displayed in real time.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is GroundPi ?

Comment: A dedicated Raspberry Pi: `https://openhd.gitbook.io/open-hd/general/faq#what-is-an-airpi-groundpi`

Comment: What is the latency requirements? If there is no requirement to have very low latency you could look to `hlssink`: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/hls/hlssink2.html

Comment: As little latency as possible - I'm trying to show a live video.

Comment: Then you will have to use WebRTC I'm afraid. You could try [Janus Server](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) to do it - it supports restreaming from UDP to WebRTC. To simplify task you could start with [Janus Snap package](https://snapcraft.io/janus-gateway) - then you could avoid build step, and also could run it directly on Raspberry PI.
Also, there is [other possible solution](https://github.com/WebRTSP/ReStreamer), but it not supports UDP as input source atm, but it can be added pretty easily (it's my project).

Comment: This project offers hardware-accelerated webRTC output to browser for the Pi, Jetson, and Linux:

https://github.com/steveseguin/raspberry_ninja  Mainly for HDMI/Camera/CSI camera inputs, but can support a raw video input pipe.